Calling docker-compose again with modified yaml causes "address already in use" for existing entry
(running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)
I built a mini daemon that will put specific USB devices and their software in their own containers.
To do so, I watch the USB devices and modify a docker-compose.yaml to add or remove services accordingly.
My understanding was:
Docker compose will not touch services of a compose file that didn't experience any changes.
It this correct?
It worked like that for multiple months..
Because if I add another USB device, I actually get an error for the existing container.
Error:
sudo docker-compose up -d
Starting lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-6_1 ...
Starting lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-6_1 ... error
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-6_1  Cannot start service t32tcpusb_3-6: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-6_1 (ad9ebc7e4999b45f5dd6590027db9d7dad3649e4eae66a21bf9887a2beb2fa0f): failed to bind port 0.0.0.0:8457/tcp: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8457: bind: address already in use
Creating lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-3_1 ... done

ERROR: for t32tcpusb_3-6  Cannot start service t32tcpusb_3-6: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint lauterbach_containerize_t32tcpusb_3-6_1 (ad9ebc7e4999b45f5dd6590027db9d7dad3649e4eae66a21bf9887a2beb2fa0f): failed to bind port 0.0.0.0:8457/tcp: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8457: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

This behavior is not like that since the beginning, so I wonder if some sw update caused it.
It is not "anyone" using the port, but the docker-proxy that is intended to do so....
Also, even after this error, the docker-proxy is still running for that container.
docker-compose.yaml before:
version: '3'
services:

    t32tcpusb_3-6:
        image: ubuntu
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb
        privileged: true

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32"
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6:/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        devices:
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        ports:
          - "8457:8455"

docker-compose.yaml after:
version: '3'
services:

    t32tcpusb_3-3:
        image: ubuntu
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb
        privileged: true

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32"
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-3:/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-3"

        devices:
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-3"

        ports:
          - "8456:8455"

    t32tcpusb_3-6:
        image: ubuntu
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb
        privileged: true

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32"
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6:/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        devices:
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        ports:
          - "8457:8455"


To answer my question:

Docker compose will not touch services of a compose file that didn't experience any changes.
It this correct?

Yes, it is correct.
The issue was with some remainder from the same container that somehow survived an unexpected reboot.
If I trear everything down before reboot, it will work fine afterwards...
